# Debug PyThread_acquire_lock deadlock

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, locking, deadlock

I have a multithreaded application running in production environment that hangs at the random time with `FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE` state of all threads and gdb shows that all the threads are trying to make lock calling `PyThread_acquire_lock`. It is really massive application with tens of thousands code lines and I can not guess in what line this error is occurred.
Can I debug this issue somehow? I can patch threading.Lock calling and log to file all locks are acquired/released in the application and then read this file in the case of error occurred again but I think that there are other python functions calling `PyThread_acquire_lock`. So how can I debug the issue? Maybe it is possible to "subscribe" on this C function call from Python and log all these calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are in one step from the answer: attach with `gdb` to deadlocked process and use Python gdb extensions to examine lines being in a deadlock.

For `gdb --version` >= 7:

```
sudo apt install python2.7-dbg python3-dbg
sudo gdb /usr/bin/python[3] <pid_of_deadlocked_process>
(gdb) thread apply all py-list
(gdb) thread 2
(gdb) py-up
(gdb) py-print <lock_object>
```

References: https://docs.python.org/devguide/gdb.html, https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb

Comment: Thank you it sounds good and I will try this when catch this bug again!